# KMail - Proxy - Module could not be found

Tags: debian, proxy, debian-jessie, cinnamon, kmail

I'm trying to configure KMail through a proxy but when I go to Settings > Misc > Proxy, the interface is blank with error messages:

> Module could not be found

And

> The desktop file could not be found.

I have checked the /usr/share/kde4/services/kmail_config_misc.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Icon=preferences-other
Type=Service
X-KDE-ServiceTypes=KCModule

X-KDE-ModuleType=Library
X-KDE-Library=kcm_kmail
X-KDE-FactoryName=kmail_config_misc
X-KDE-HasReadOnlyMode=false
X-KDE-ParentApp=kmail
X-KDE-ParentComponents=kmail,kontact_kmailplugin
X-KDE-CfgDlgHierarchy=KMail
X-KDE-Weight=600
X-DocPath=kmail/index.html#configure-misce here
```

The rest of file contain only translations.

I'm on Cinnamon under Debian Jessy.
I'have installed KMail with apt-get.

Thank's for your help.

Comment: Did you tried to reinstall from scratch `kmail`? (After that you backup all the mailboxes)? ToDoList: 1) Backup 2) dis-install 3) re install. If still doesn't work 2b) dis-install `apt-get remove --purge` then 3b) Install again. Use the option `--purge`  to delete even the settings. Please [edit] your question adding the version of KDE, kmail. BTW Cinnamon is derived from Gnome, kmail is part of KDE. Maybe you need to install many other packages. Look with attention the suggested packages too when you install kmail.